# I have 2 strings and i want to separate them by using Regular Expression

Tags: regex

```
([a-zA-Z\s\,\-\']+)([0-9\s:]+)
```

I have tried this approach and it's not working for the given strings
Please suggest me some modifications in my RegEx Code

```
Digital and Electronics - 103 : 24
IPV6 Types08 : 03
```

**I want to separate the time part only from the text**

```
('03 : 24')
('08 : 03')
```

Comment: Why does `103 : 24` become `3 : 24` and `08 : 03` becomes `08 : 03`

Comment: Thank you for taking interest in my question

Comment: Actually that is my task only I want to separate my strings according to this fact only

Comment: But @jaydeeptewary; if there is no proper pattern then regex cannot help you. Regular expressions work on patterns. If this is static string; then it is possible or if you need to separate three digit numbers on `0` then it is possible. But if no pattern is there then it it wll be a problem

Comment: What is the logic to get those separate parts?

Comment: I have changed my question now if u can please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
\d\d : \d\d
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/1fMn3R/1).

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
import re

regex = r"\d\d : \d\d(?:$|\Z)"

test_str = ("Digital and Electronics - 103 : 24\n"
    "IPV6 Types08 : 03")

print( re.findall(regex, test_str, flags=re.M) )
```

to get

```
['03 : 24', '08 : 03']
```